# How to reshape a dataframe (different type in columns)

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

I have seen many different answer about this topic. In my situation the case is a bit diffrent , I have the following dataframe

```
     A    B      C  
0  OPXXX  OPT1 70
1  OPXXX  OPT2 KO
2  OPXXX  OPT3 KO
3  OPXXX  OPT4 B
4  OPXXX  OPT5 175000
5  OPXXX  OPT6 Europ
6  OPXXX  OPT7 2019-01-21
7  OPXXX  OPT8 2019-05-21
8  OPXXX  OPT9 2019-10-21
```

I would like to have it like that but the issue is pivot.table is not working because of the aggreagtion function:

> ```
>  A     OPT1  OPT2 OPT3 OPT4 OPT5   OPT6         OPT7       OPT8         OPT9    
> OPXXX   70     KO    KO   B 175000  Europe    2019-01-21  2019-10-21  2019-10-21
> ```

when I do : df.pivot(index='A',values='C', columns= 'B')

Ihave the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/V002697/PycharmProjects/portia/tiaex.py", line 17, in
>   
>       print(df.pivot(index='ticker',values='value', columns= 'field'))   File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 3853, in pivot
>       return pivot(self, index=index, columns=columns, values=values)   File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py",
>   line 378, in pivot
>       return indexed.unstack(columns)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py",
>   line 2028, in unstack
>       return unstack(self, level, fill_value)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py",
>   line 458, in unstack
>       fill_value=fill_value)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py",
>   line 110, in **init**
>       self._make_selectors()   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py",
>   line 148, in _make_selectors
>       raise ValueError('Index contains duplicate entries, ' ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

I would like to know if you have some ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: The error is saying that you have duplicated items in `'B'` thus it cannot be made into an index.

Comment: In column  'A' I have duplicates tike in my example, 'B' does not  have any duplicates

Comment: Example you provide works perfectly fine. Can you check if `len(df.B) - df.B.nunique()` is 0?

Comment: you are great thanks I had to time the same column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.pivot`:

```
df.pivot(index='A', columns = 'B', values='C')

B     OPT1 OPT2 OPT3 OPT4    OPT5   OPT6        OPT7        OPT8        OPT9
A                                                                           
OPXXX   70   KO   KO    B  175000  Europ  2019-01-21  2019-05-21  2019-10-21
```

Comment: I already tried this I have a traceback for df.pivot(index=["A"],values=["C"], columns= 'B'):ine 3853, in pivot
    return pivot(self, index=index, columns=columns, values=values), line 377, in pivot
    index=MultiIndex.from_arrays([index, self[columns]]))

Comment: Have you tried without `[]`? i.e. `"A"` instead of `["A"]`?

Comment: I tried df.pivot(index='A',values='C', columns= 'B') but I still have the same errors

Comment: `df.pivot(index='A',values='c', columns= 'field')` is referring to the columns that were not in the given example of your question. Please edit your question if there is any other information you can share :)

Comment: misspell you were too quick :) df.pivot(index='A',values='C', columns= 'B')

Answer (score 0):

df1 = df.rename(columns={'A':'A1', 'B':'B1', 'A1':'A2', 'B1':'B2'}).reset_index()
pd.wide_to_long(df1, stubnames=['A', 'B'], i='index', j='id')\
  .reset_index()[['A', 'B', 'id']]

```
A   B id
```

0   1   2  1
1   5   6  1
2   9  10  1
3   3   4  2
4   7   8  2
5  11  12  2